# Asp.net resx file update without ending session?

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, resources, resx

I have globalresource file when i'm updating a value then automatically logout from the web site and i need to login again to change another value.

Can we update language files (resx) without session logout?

I need a solution for this situation.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is your current Session storage/mode? If it's memory (`InProc`), then an application recycles will clear Session data. You'll need to use [different mode/storage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178586.aspx) that survives application recycling - e.g. `StateSever` or `SQLServer`

### [ASP.NET File Change Notifications, exactly which files and directories are monitored?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/tmarq/2007/11/01/asp-net-file-change-notifications-exactly-which-files-and-directories-are-monitored/)

> 2)  The `bin`, `App_Code`, `App_WebReferences`, `App_GlobalResources`, and `App_Browsers` subdirectories of the application root folder are monitored for creation, deletion, renaming, ACL changes, changes to the last-write time, and changes to the size.  If any of these things change, the AppDomain is unloaded.....

Hth...